# Is disabling 'CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls' a good way of blocking cross-threading errors?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have many threads running in my C# application and each of those threads accesses a `TextBox` to log its events. When I set the [CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `false`, I am able to block many cross-threading errors:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'myTextBox'
accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

What is the best solution for this problem? Using delegates or disabling `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` as I have tried? Many articles say that disabling `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is not a good programming practice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disabling `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is like complaining that you get hit by an airbag when crashing your car: the correct solution isn't to remove the airbag, it's to avoid crashing the car.

You simply shouldn't be making UI updates from the wrong thread. You *may* get away with it most of the time (having disabled the check) but that doesn't mean that it's a good idea - it leaves you open to subtle errors which will only show up occasionally and be *really* hard to track down.

So yes, use `Control.Invoke`, `Dispatcher.Invoke`, `BackgroundWorker` etc to marshal to the right thread for UI access. That's why those calls/types exist.

Answer (score 0):

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377543/1282539) to a different question has the answer to you.
The short answer is: No.
Switch to BackgroundWorkers.