# How to implement a logging window in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

So using windows form builder, I have created a new form with textbox in it, calling this form as LogForm.cs, this form/class has a method called log(string text).

In my main form class (Form1.cs), I have created an instance of that form.

```
LogForm logForm = new LogForm();
logForm.log("Logger has started...");
```

and it show fine on the LogForm textbox. But when I call `logForm.log("Some logging info...")` On my code inside a thread, it somehow makes my application crash.

How do I deal with this? Please help me demostrate a small code.I am fairly new to C# and programming as a whole so I hope you consider.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multithreading with Winform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369819/how-to-use-multithreading-with-winform)

Answer (score 0):

Use/call this function in `LogForm.log` (btw methods in C# are usually capitalized).

```
private void SetText(string text)
{
    Action set = () => yourTextBox.Text = text;

    if (yourTextBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        yourTextBox.Invoke(set);
    }
    else
    {
        set.Invoke();
    }
}
```

If it cannot be set from the current thread `yourTextBox.InvokeRequired` will be true and the function will work it out. Otherwise it just sets it directly.

Inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369906/10883465) at [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369819/how-to-use-multithreading-with-winform).

Since you are saying the problem persists I'll show a bit more code and try to expain it further.

First of all, I edited the `SetText` method. I added the private modifier since this function is not indended to be called anywhere outside of `LogForm`. I also added the curly brackets since that's my preferred style and it also makes sure that the if-statement behaves as expected.

```
public void Log(string message) {
    SetText(message);
    //do stuff
}
```

Both of these methods (`Log` and `SetText`) are placed inside the `LogForm` class. You can now call `logForm.Log("Logger has started...");` from any thread as long as your form (containing the textbox) is already initialized. This usually happens in the constructor by calling `InitializeComponent();` on the first line.

Without knowing more about your code this is probably as far as I can help you.

Comment: I have done it as you said, but it still not wroking right, it freezes the application and crashes it.

Comment: Would you consider showing more of your code?
I tested the snipped with a normal windows-form and called the method once from the UI-Thread and once from a completely seperate thread. It worked both times.

Comment: Check if my edit helps. If not please edit your question and add your definition of the log function which isn't working as expected.